# npm lifecycle error after restarting

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, visual-studio-code

I am learning Angular 2 using Visual Studio Code as IDE. Everything runs OK for executing "npm start" the first time. But, if I try to break the process with CTRL+C, and then write "npm start" again, I gain the error:

```
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

It seems to me like it's not killing the previous process, but don't know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears without command `npm install` before.
Steps to run application:

1. Run `npm install` command  (waiting...):

   `... added 116 packages in 16.745s`
2. Run `npm start` command:

   `...
   [1] 17.11.21 16:37:37 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/isObject.js
   [1] 17.11.21 16:37:37 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/tryCatch.js
   [1] 17.11.21 16:37:37 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/errorObject.js
   [1] 17.11.21 16:37:37 304 GET /node_modules/rxjs/util/UnsubscriptionError.js`
3. Open `http://localhost:port` in your browser  to see product